# Unable to run dotnet core preview 2 project using docker

Tags: .net, azure, docker, docker-compose

I am not able to run docker containers on windows server 2016 on dotnet core preview 2. I am able to build to docker container but during run I receive the following error.

```
Creating network "dockercompose_default" with the default driver

Creating dockercompose_flousermanagement_1 ...

Creating dockercompose_flousermanagement_1 ... done

Attaching to dockercompose_flousermanagement_1

flousermanagement_1  | The specified framework 'Microsoft.NETCore.App', version '2.0.0-preview2-25407-01' was not found.

flousermanagement_1  |   - Check application dependencies and target a framework version installed at:

flousermanagement_1  |       C:\Program  
Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App

flousermanagement_1  |   - The following versions are installed:

flousermanagement_1  |       1.0.5

flousermanagement_1  |       1.1.2

flousermanagement_1  |   - Alternatively, install the framework version '2.0.0-preview2-25407-01'.

dockercompose_flousermanagement_1 exited with code 2147516547
```

I have checked the program files shared location folder and .net core 2.0.0-preview2-25407-01 is installed but docker-compose is unable to pick the new framework. Whereas I am able to run docker containers on dotnet core 1.0 & 1.1.
I am using the following server configuration for deployment.
Windows Server 2016 Datacenter

Intel Xeon 2.4GHz Dual Core.
x64 bit
7GB RAM.
I am using Docker enterprise and not the community edition.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution to my problem. Actually I was using the container image of a previous version of dotnet core like microsoft/dotnet:nanoserver which was perhaps built using old framework like 1.1 or 1.2. 
But when I changed the container image to 2.0.0-preview2-sdk-nanoserver the microservice started working.

Thank you.